# Calculate column values from previous rows in different columns

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to update the values of a given column based on values stored in the previous row but from different columns.

I can do it using a for loop that works well with small data sets but when dealing with large DT (say over 1MM rows) this procedure off course takes ages. The following is a small example:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(Year = 2019:2038, Area = 500, Cos = c(0,0,0,150,0,0,
  0,0,350,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,120,200,80,100), Rep = c(0,0,0,0,150,0,0,0,0,
  350,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), Calc = c(500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,
  500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,380,180,100))
```

Basically, I want to replicate the column "Calc" which is calculated as follow:

1) If row == 1

```
Calc[1] == Area[1]
```

2) For rows > 1

```
Calc[i] == Rep[i] + Calc[i-1] - Cos[i-1]
```

I would appreciate any feedback

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you can use:

```
DT[, newCalc := Calc[1L] + cumsum(Rep - shift(Cos, fill=0L))]
```

output:

```
    Year Area Cos Rep Calc    d newCalc
 1: 2019  500   0   0  500    0     500
 2: 2020  500   0   0  500    0     500
 3: 2021  500   0   0  500    0     500
 4: 2022  500 150   0  500    0     500
 5: 2023  500   0 150  500    0     500
 6: 2024  500   0   0  500    0     500
 7: 2025  500   0   0  500    0     500
 8: 2026  500   0   0  500    0     500
 9: 2027  500 350   0  500    0     500
10: 2028  500   0 350  500    0     500
11: 2029  500   0   0  500    0     500
12: 2030  500   0   0  500    0     500
13: 2031  500   0   0  500    0     500
14: 2032  500   0   0  500    0     500
15: 2033  500   0   0  500    0     500
16: 2034  500   0   0  500    0     500
17: 2035  500 120   0  500    0     500
18: 2036  500 200   0  380 -120     380
19: 2037  500  80   0  180 -200     180
20: 2038  500 100   0  100  -80     100
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`

```
DT[, newCalc := Reduce(`+`, Rep - shift(Cos, fill = 0), 
         init = Area[1], accumulate = TRUE)[-1]]
DT
#    Year Area Cos Rep Calc newCalc
# 1: 2019  500   0   0  500     500
# 2: 2020  500   0   0  500     500
# 3: 2021  500   0   0  500     500
# 4: 2022  500 150   0  500     500
# 5: 2023  500   0 150  500     500
# 6: 2024  500   0   0  500     500
# 7: 2025  500   0   0  500     500
# 8: 2026  500   0   0  500     500
# 9: 2027  500 350   0  500     500
#10: 2028  500   0 350  500     500
#11: 2029  500   0   0  500     500
#12: 2030  500   0   0  500     500
#13: 2031  500   0   0  500     500
#14: 2032  500   0   0  500     500
#15: 2033  500   0   0  500     500
#16: 2034  500   0   0  500     500
#17: 2035  500 120   0  500     500
#18: 2036  500 200   0  380     380
#19: 2037  500  80   0  180     180
#20: 2038  500 100   0  100     100
```

---

Or the same with `accumulate` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
DT %>% 
   mutate(newCalc = accumulate(Rep - lag(Cos, default = 0),
          .init = first(Area), `+`)[-1])
```